# Suggest the best thread group to simulate 20 requests every second for a minute (Total number of requests should be equal to 1200)

Tags: jmeter

Suggest the best thread group and values to simulate 20 requests every second for a minute (Total number of requests should be equal to 1200 irrespective of request response time).

Details:
Hi, We have a request from an user to test the api performance when below use case is executed.

1. Only 20 requests should be sent in the first second (total number of request at this second - 20)
2. Next set of 20 requests should be sent in the second second (total number of request at this second - 40)
3. Next set of 20 requests should be sent in the third second (total number of request at this second - 60)
   .....

and the requests should sent until 60 seconds
.
.

60. At 60th second, total number requests sent to system should be 1200.

We tried with Thread Group with Threads - 20, Rampup - 0, Loop - Infinte, Duration - 60 seconds.

What we observed is when the requests have good success rate - the number of samples count is near to 400 and when api is down - the number of requests being sent are around 18000.

User want the number to be constant i.e. 1200 always irrespective of the api success or failure

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to achieve 20 requests per second with 20 users only if your API response time is 1 second sharp.

If the response time will be 2 seconds - you will get 10 requests per second

If the response time will be 500 milliseconds - you will get 40 requests per second

So you need to:

1. Provide the sufficient amount of threads in order to reach the desired throughput. It depends on your API response time
2. In order to limit JMeter's throughput to 20 requests per second use a Timer

The easiest way of achieving this is using:

1. [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) to precisely set the desired number of requests per second
2. [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) as it can be connected to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads if the current amount is not sufficient

And of course your API must be able to handle the load of 20 requests per second because if it isn't - no matter what you do from JMeter side you won't be able to achieve the target rate because JMeter waits for the response from the previous request prior to starting the next one.